# Rails 3 Authlogic problem with single access token and logout on timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm having a problem using an authlogic single access token to access a page when logout on timeout is set to true and a timeout is set.

user.rb:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.logged_in_timeout = 15.minutes
end
```

user_session.rb:

```
logout_on_timeout true
```

controller:

```
def single_access_allowed?
  ["download_xml"].include?(action_name)
end
```

If I try to access a page/method using the token it redirects straight away to my login page. The logout on timeout works when its turned on.

**If i remove the timeout code and just have acts_as_authentic in the user.rb, the single access token works.**

I want to be able to use the single access token so another application can open an xml file from my ruby on rails website.

**Any ideas on what I might have done wrong and where to look to fix it and make it work?**

Using authlogic 3.0.3 and rails 3.0.7.

Comment: I still havn't figured this one out if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: found this as an open issue on github for authlogic ->
https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/64

mhaley says:


"If you just want to fix the problem in your app you can modify your
UserSession model like so: "


    class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
     before_persisting :reset_stale_state, :unless => :single_access?
     after_persisting :enforce_timeout, :unless => :single_access?
    end

However, the single access token works but then logout on timeout stops working.

Answer (score 0):

This reply from jgdreyes last Sept 27 at https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/64 worked for me:

> I went ahead and extended Authlogic's stale? method so that it does
>   not see requests as stale? if accessing via single_access?. This keeps
>   logic for logout_on_timeout intact.

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base   logout_on_timeout true
  def stale?
    return false if single_access?
    super   
  end 
end
```