# I'm using Authlogic with multiple sessions - how should I expire just one type of session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

Since my app involves payment, I have a regular UserSession as well as a UserSession with id == :secure to protect the areas of the app involving money. The regular session doesn't need to expire, but the secure session should expire after a period of inactivity.

Here's what I have so far

## models/User.rb

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.session_ids = [nil,:secure]
  c.logged_in_timeout(5.minutes)
  ...
end
```

## models/UserSession.rb

```
self.logout_on_timeout = true
```

I thought of extending the stale? method, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703351/rails-3-authlogic-problem-with-single-access-token-and-logout-on-timeout) question :

```
def stale?
  return false if self.id != :secure
  super
end
```

but that doesn't work because session.id doesn't refer to the id column in the database...anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
Other ideas...

- set some instance-method version of logout_on_timeout on sessions when I create them. That way I could set secure_session.logout_on_timeout = true, but not regular_session
- go outside of Authlogic and use a cron sweeper or something - this seems sorta ridiculous if I want to run the job every 5 minutes
- create a whole new session model, called SecureSession, that has logout_on_timeout == true, and is somehow also associated with my User model

C'mon guys, anyone have a creative solution here?